# Get longest list as goal in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I have more possible list as goal,but i need only one longest list.Is this possible to get first longest list?

```
li-->[a]|[b]|[c].
int-->['1']|['2']|['3'].
num-->int,num_nl.
num_nl-->num|[].
list1-->num,li.
classify(L,S,R):-list1(S,[]),extract(S,L,R).
extract(S,L1,L2):-append(L11,L22,L1),append(S,L3,L22),append(L11,L3,L2).
```

Here ERROR: Out of local stack.I want only longest list as goal:

```
?-classify([c,'1','1',a,f],S,R).
S = ['1', '1', a], R = [c, f] ;
false.
?-classify([c,'1','2','3',a,f,'1','1','2','3',b],S,R).
S = ['1','2','3',a], R = [c, f,'1','1','2','3',b] ;
false.`
```

Comment: Can you show how the classify predicate look? hard to help otherwise

Comment: ok. Now I add the pridicate.is possible to get the answer?

Comment: This is quite messy. Have you tried debugging it yourself? What are you trying to achieve, exactly? What answers do you expect from that query?

Comment: This query i want find longest possible list of List1 that is `?-classify([c,'1','2','3',a,f,'1','1','2','3',b],S,R).` is scan left to right, Here [a],['3',a],['2','3',a],['1','2','3',a] are first possible lists, but i want longest list ['1','2','3',a] is a goal, in this case ['1','1','2','3',b] is a longest but i need scan left to right and get possible is ['1','2','3',a].

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide any detail on how `classify/1` is implemented; it could be that you can define it so that it only gives you the longest list.

Your other option is to collect all results, using either `findall/3` or `bagof/3` or `setof/3`, then make pairs with the list length as the first element, then sort these pairs and pick the last.

For example:

```
?- bagof(X, classify(X), Xs),
   maplist(length, X, Lengths),
   pairs_keys_values(Ps, Lengths, Xs),
   keysort(Ps, Sorted),
   last(_-Longest, Sorted).
```

It uses [`pairs_keys_values/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/swipl/lib/swipl/library/pairs.pl?show=src#pairs_keys_values/3) and [`last/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/swipl/lib/swipl/library/lists.pl?show=src#last/2) as defined in the SWI-Prolog standard libraries.

This approach will work, even though it has several problems. It is difficult to discuss those without any knowledge of what `classify/1` does.

Comment: I edit the question and I add the pridicate.is possible to get the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I used at least once a convoluted variant of Boris' answer

```
?- R=[_-S|_],setof(L-X,T^(classify(X),length(X,T),L is -1*T),R).
```